# Hide a header and footer for a specific webpage with either CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hide

Thanks in advance with any help you can provide on this one!

My website has this structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>
Content
<footer></footer>
</body>
<html>
```

How can I make it so that one page within the website does not display the header or the footer?

I've tried jquery .hide, but it hides these elements for all pages. I know I'm missing something easy, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: so from html to </header>  and from <footer> to </html> is common part for all pages in your site?

Comment: You said you are using jQuery's `hide` method.  That is all you need, but only do it on the pages you want to hide the header/footer.

Comment: Yeah, what Kyle said, I'm failing to understand the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really seeing an issue, just put this in each page that you want to hide the header/footer in:

```
$(function() {
    $("header, footer").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbVxw/

Comment: Guys, this one's on me. I apologize; I'm using mobify to build a mobiel site, and it puts code together in blocks that sometimes conflict with one another. The code that you provided, @ach, worked just fine as soon as I cleared out some conflicts from another area of the site. Thank you for the fix.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>

 //START OF CONTENT PAGE
 //write the hiding code here for header and footer on document.ready

<script type='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("header, footer").hide();
});
</script>



Content

 //END OF CONTENT PAGE
<footer></footer>
</body>
<html>
```